# How to fix Memory Error when arranging 11 elements choosen from 30 elements in python using itertools library?

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I have a list of cricket players of both the teams.

Let's say there are a total of 30 players, and I want to select 11 players randomly from those 30. I want all the combinations to be stored in a list.

I've tried to use itertools.permutations from python. But I'm getting a `MemoryError`. Is there any way to fix this or any other libraries in Python that I can use?

```
from itertools import permutations   
name=["p1","p2","p3","p4","p5","p6","p7","p8","p9","p10","p11","p12","p13","p14","p15","p16","p17","p18","p19","p20","p21","p22","p23","p24","p25","p26","p27","p28","p29","p30"]  
combinations = list(permutations(name,11))
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "PythonDemo.py", line 3, in <module>  
    combinations = list(permutations(name,11))  
MemoryError
```

Comment: how many times do you need to select 11 players? the number of permutations with 11 elements is pretty high, and when you stored it in memory, you get memory error

Comment: Why do you need *all* permutations in a list?  What are you doing with it?  (As you have seen, it is a *very* big list.)

Answer (score 1):

Choosing 11 elements out of 30 can be done in `30!/(30 - 11)!` ways, which is about `2e+16`. Thus, the list you want will take up several exabytes of memory!

As pre-computing all permutations is utterly out of the question, may I suggest using [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
import random

name = ["p1","p2","p3","p4","p5","p6","p7","p8","p9","p10","p11","p12","p13","p14","p15","p16","p17","p18","p19","p20","p21","p22","p23","p24","p25","p26","p27","p28","p29","p30"]

for i in range(3):
    combination = random.choices(name, k=11)
    print(combination)
```

Note that `random.choices` is only available as of Python 3.6.

#### Keep using itertools.permutations

You can also stick to `itertools.permutations`, e.g. by keeping a generator alive like so:

```
from itertools import permutations

name = ["p1","p2","p3","p4","p5","p6","p7","p8","p9","p10","p11","p12","p13","p14","p15","p16","p17","p18","p19","p20","p21","p22","p23","p24","p25","p26","p27","p28","p29","p30"]  
combinations = permutations(name, 11)

for i in range(3):
    combination = next(combinations)
    print(combination)
```

Note that this will not pick a combination at random, but instead result in very predictable combinations. This may be good or bad dependent on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the iterator generated by the permutations instead of recreating a list with it.

```
import itertools

name = [f'p{a}' for a in range(1, 31)]
combinations = itertools.permutations(name, 11)

for item in combinations:
   do_the_stuff(item)
```